# Swift viewForAnnotation pin zposition not on top

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, pins

In Swift i will try to set pin location(zPosition) on Top ,I am adding 10 pin on Map ,Current pin(Any one pin) showing on top and these current pin image is change, But its not showing on top , Please help me Here is my Code 
I have Try These code

```
// pinView!.layer.zPosition = 1
//pinView?.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)
pinView!.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(view)
```

App Crash on These Line

```
pinView!.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(view)
```

and Its return me 
**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**
Please Help me How to pin show on Top

Here is my Code

```
  func mapView(mapView: MKMapView,
        viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView?{

            if annotation is MyAnnotation == false{
                return nil
            }

            /* First typecast the annotation for which the Map View has
            fired this delegate message */
            let senderAnnotation = annotation as! MyAnnotation



            // --------------------------    For ios 9 -------------------


            let reuseId = "pin"
            var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)

            if pinView == nil {
                pinView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
                pinView!.canShowCallout = true

            }else{
                pinView!.annotation = annotation
            }
            pinView!.tag = senderAnnotation.getTag;

          //  print(senderAnnotation.getTag)

            if annotation is MyAnnotation {

                print(senderAnnotation.pinColor)
                if(senderAnnotation.pinColor == .Red)
                {
                    if(currentIndex == senderAnnotation.getTag)
                    {
                        print("currentIndex==\(currentIndex)********")
                        pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "jivemap_pin_rough_o.png")
                       // pinView!.layer.zPosition = 1
                        //pinView?.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)
                        pinView!.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(view)
                    }else
                    {
                        pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "jivemap_pin_rough_g.png")
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                if(currentIndex == senderAnnotation.getTag)
                {
                    print("currentIndex==*********\(currentIndex)********")
                    pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "jivemap_pin_o.png")
                   // pinView!.layer.zPosition = 1
                    //pinView?.bringSubviewToFront(self.view)

                            pinView!.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(view)


                }else
                {
                    pinView!.image = UIImage(named: "jivemap_pin_g.png")
                }
            }

                pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure) as UIView
              // pinView
               // return pinView
            }





            return pinView
            //return annotationView

    }
```

I have one more problem , **Can we select the zoom to show all the 10 pins together** Any Solution For these point how to set zoom lever, Camera level to show all 10 pins on map view 
When i search for these point i found these code but i cant able to understand how to use these code.

```
CGFloat latDelta = rand()*0.125/RAND_MAX - 0.02;
       CGFloat lonDelta = rand()*0.130/RAND_MAX - 0.08;

       CGFloat lat = 59.189358;
       CGFloat lng = 18.267839;

       CLLocationCoordinate2D newCoord = {lat+latDelta, lng+lonDelta};

       DTSAnnotation *annotation = [DTSAnnotation annotationWithCoord:newCoord];
```

Please Help me for solving these Two point to Related map 
Thankyou

Comment: Maybe a few screenshots will help.

Comment: OK i will add , but the problem is i have 10 pins 9 pin are same and 1 pin is another image so these one pin is dont want to back to other pins i have to set on top of

Answer (score 0):

Regarding first point I had the same issue with that. The mistake is in that line of code `pinView!.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(view)`. 
As you want bring to the front pinView you have to do like this `pinView!.superview!.bringSubviewToFront(pinView)`.
Because you taking superview of pinView and have to set that pinView to front. For me it's working.